# How to select 2nd Level SubMenu in Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying all possible answers that were provided for similar Query.

My lay-out Structure of the Menu:

MainMenu1  , Manimenu2.... etc
Under Each Mainmenu

```
   Submenu1>Item1, Item2, Item3
   Submenu2>Item1, Item2, Item3
   Submenu3>Item1, Item2, Item3
```

To get to Item1 or Item2 or Item3, we have to move the mouse over and hover it over Mainmenu1>submenu1 and then click Item2

I was able to use mouse-hover command and get it open the Mainmenu but unable to get past it.

Any suggestions Please?

Thankyou.

Comment: Did you use **AdvancedUserInteractions**, if yes then what happened? Please show us how did you try to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

After mouse-hovering `mainmenu1` you need to find `submenu1` and then perform mouse-hover

```
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
        WebElement mainmenu1 = driver.findElement(By.xxxxx());
        builder.moveToElement(mainmenu1 ).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(500); //add a wait
        WebElement submenu1=  driver.findElement(By.xxxxx()); //Find the submenu
        builder.moveToElement(submenu1).click().build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(500);
```

Comment: Actions a = new Actions(driver); 
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#admin")); 
a.moveToElement(menuHoverLink); 
WebElement subLink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".companyinfo")); 
a.moveToElement(subLink); 
Thread.sleep(5000L);
WebElement subLink3 = driver.findElement(By.className("companyinfo")); 
a.moveToElement(subLink3); 
a.click(); 
a.build().perform();
Thread.sleep(5000L);
WebElement subLink4 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#admin >ul>li:nth-child(1)>ul>li:nth-child(3)>a>span")); 
actions.moveToElement(subLink4);
a.click(); a.build().perform();

Comment: I can see it hover open; but not clicking it open;

Comment: wait for it and        click it

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it will help you

```
 new Actions(wd)
    .moveToElement(
            wd.findElement(By
                    .linkText("MainMenu1")))
    .build().perform();
 Thread.sleep(500);
 wd.findElement(By.linkText("Item1")).click();
```